# Help Optimizing a MySQL SELECT with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, indexing

Currently the table has the following indexes:

1. forum_id_index
2. other_forum_id_index
3. forum_id_on_other_forum_id_index => [forum_id, other_forum_id]

The query:

```
SELECT `topics.*` 
FROM `topics` 
WHERE (table.forum_id = ? OR table.other_forum_id = ?) 
ORDER by sticky, replied_at DESC LIMIT 25
```

I've tried adding indexes on the following:

1. sticky
2. replied_at
3. [sticky, replied_at]
4. [forum_id, other_forum_id, sticky, replied_at]
5. [sticky, replied_at, forum_id, other_forum_id]

This is for a forum, trying to get the top 25 topics in the forum, but placing `sticky` topics (sticky is a binary field for sticky/nonsticky) at the top.

I've read pretty much everything I can get my hands on about optimizing `ORDER BY`, but no luck. This is on `MySQL 5.1, INNODB`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDITS**

As requested in comments (sorry if I'm doing this wrong - new to posting on SU). Results of EXPLAIN currently:

> id = 1
>
> select_type = SIMPLE
>
> table = topics
>
> type = index_merge
>
> possible_keys = index_topics_on_forum_id,index_topics_on_sticky_and_replied_at,index_topics_on_forum_id_and_replied_at,index_topics_on_video_forum_id,index_forum_id_on_video_forum_id,
>
> keys = index_topics_on_forum_id,index_topics_on_video_forum_id
>
> key_len = 5,5
>
> ref = NULL
>
> rows = 13584
>
> Extra =  Using union(index_topics_on_forum_id,index_topics_on_video_forum_id); Using where; Using filesort

SHOW INDEXES FROM topics returns https://gist.github.com/1079454 - Couldn't get formatting to show up here well.

**EDIT 2**

```
SELECT `topics`.*
FROM `topics`
WHERE topics.forum_id=4
ORDER BY sticky desc, replied_at DESC
```

Runs incredibly fast (1.4ms). So does the query when I change topics.forum_id to topics.video_forum_id - just not when I have them both in the query with an or.

Comment: Can you show the output for: `SHOW INDEXES FROM topics` ?

Can you show the output for: `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` ? (So just place the word `EXPLAIN` in front of your query.

Comment: @entity How many rows it returns without LIMIT 25?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be very fast.

Indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `topics` 
    ADD INDEX `forum` (`forum_id` ASC, `sticky` ASC, `replied_at` DESC), 
    ADD INDEX `other_forum` (`other_forum_id` ASC, `sticky` ASC, `replied_at` DESC);
```

Query:

```
(
    SELECT `topics.*` 
    FROM `topics` USE INDEX (`forum`)
    WHERE `topics`.forum_id = ?
    ORDER by sticky, replied_at DESC 
    LIMIT 25
) UNION (
    SELECT `topics.*` 
    FROM `topics` USE INDEX (`other_forum`)
    WHERE `topics`.other_forum_id = ?
    ORDER by sticky, replied_at DESC 
    LIMIT 25
)
ORDER by sticky, replied_at DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this without Unions, as I'm calling this from Rails right now. Worst case scenario I can use Model.find_by_sql but I'm trying to avoid embedding too much pure sql in our models.

Comment: Hmm - I ran that query w/those indexes and it was actually slower than the current (not by much - 300ms vs 250ms). It's just bizarre that without the OR (i.e. just SELECT topics.* FROM topics WHERE topics.forum_id = ? ORDER BY sticky, replied_at DESC) - it's incredibly fast, and the same is true if it's JUST the video_forum_id. But when it includes the OR it's much slower.

Comment: @entity I am a little surprised that query without **OR** runs instantly, but UNION of these two fast queries - NOT. Have you used the same indexes and query as in my answer (without any modification)? `ASC/DESC` parts in indexes and in `ORDER BY` clauses MUST be the same. It would be very useful to see an EXPLAIN of my query and an EXPLAIN of the fast query without OR. I believe this will give us better understanding of the problem. By the way, instead of `USE INDEX` you may try `FORCE INDEX`.

Answer (score 0):

Try indexes [forum_id, sticky, replied_at desc] and [other_forum_id, sticky, replied_at desc]

You might try wording the query as a union, as well:

```
    SELECT `topics.*` FROM `topics` WHERE (table.forum_id = ?)
UNION
SELECT `topics.*` FROM `topics` WHERE (table.other_forum_id = ?)
 ORDER by sticky, replied_at DESC LIMIT 25
```

Comment: The idea about two indexes is good, but I think they will not work for your query :) I don't think it's possible to sort using index when UNION was applied.

Comment: @Karolis -- Yeah, my hope was that the optimizer would recognize that both queries could use the index to return in the right order, and then do a merge sort.  That's a lot to ask of the optimizer, though.  In any case, with the two indices this should be a very quick query to perform.  If the original version or the UNION form doesn't work quickly, you have to find the right way to break it up so the optimizer does the sensible thing, perhaps using temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) command to learn about the cost associated with your query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

Look out for table-scans, which are likely to be costly.

Moreover, MySQL may or may not use an index. This solely depends on how the query optimizer understands your query.

`FORCE INDEX` might be of help, since this option tells MySQL, that table-scans will be super-costly. Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 things:

- One, with indexes on:

  - `(forum_id, sticky, replied_at)`
  - `(other_forum_id, sticky, replied_at)`

either with your original query or Karolis' suggestion or

- Two, with indexes on:

  - `(forum_id)`
  - `(other_forum_id)`
  - `(sticky, replied_at)`